# MATLAB color segmentation

Tags: matlab, colors, image-segmentation

I have to write this function in matlab to color segment an image based on euclidean or mahalanobis distance. You pass in the training data for euclidean, training data and cov matrix for mahalobis.

I get the theory and math here and how to write a function in matlab but I have no idea how to segment the image RGB and do this at all. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? LOOPS are not allowed.

thanks

Comment: Thanks but I need some thing more like the actual math to segment it.My book uses dist = sgrt(sum(abs(f - remat(m,p,1).^2,2))

Comment: I get that math but they do this to  custom operation called imstack2vectors for f and that makes no sense to me why they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this site](http://math.uci.edu/icamp/courses/math77c/lab/) it has a script wich [implements Segment image RGB](http://math.uci.edu/icamp/courses/math77c/lab/cartoonify.m)

Comment: Thanks its not what I need, I need to use more of the euclidean and mahalanobis math to do it